# Suppose A is a transitive set. Prove that P(A) is also a transitive set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Anyone has any idea on how to proof the statement? I have been struggling as I don't even know how to start

Comment: ps: P(A) means the power set of A

Comment: In general, always start by writing down the definitions. What you are given, and what you need to verify. That often helps to sort your thoughts towards a solution.